# Mapping has-a relation ship in a class marked `@MappedSuperClass` in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my project, I have multiple entities inheriting from `Profile` class. The `Profile` class **has-a** `ContactDetails` which in turn **has-a** `List<Contact>`. Below is the min setup:

**UserProfile**

```
@Entity
public class UserProfile extends Profile {
    // Members of UserProfile
}
```

**Profile**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Profile {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            optional = false
    )
    private ContactDetails contactDetails;

    // Other members
}
```

**ContactDetails**

```
@Entity
public class ContactDetails {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    // Other fields
}
```

When I run this setup inside a spring boot application, I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown entity name: org.brokencodes.apps.worker.common.beans.ContactDetails
    at org.hibernate.cfg.PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.doSecondPass(PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1650) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Fixing the exception is just one part of the problem. More importantly, I would like to know if **has-a** relations even allowed in `@MappedSuperClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to replicate your setup [as follows](https://github.com/fladdimir/so-jpa/tree/mapped-superclass/src/main/java/org/demo/mappedSuperclass), I did not discover any problems while running [this integration-test](https://github.com/fladdimir/so-jpa/blob/mapped-superclass/src/test/java/org/demo/mappedSuperclass/MappedSuperclassTest.java)).

So yes it is possible and your setup seems correct so far, so there must be a different problem somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your repository. Let me check what went wrong. Most probably, then, this would be some small slip. Will comment back after verifying.

Comment: Well! I have checked everything but do not see why this should work for you and not me. The setup is almost identical.

Comment: ok.. let me know in case you got another idea of where the error might come from, or when you provided additional details that might help to reveal the problem

Comment: This is ridiculous! I did not add the package containing the class `ContactDetails` inside of `@EntityScan`. After rectifying this, it works as expected. Thank you very much @fladdimir for your help and really appreciate the time you have invested in verifying that the code is actually correct.